# android dex JPA annotation lost?

Tags: android, jpa, annotations, entity, eclipselink

JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Error on runtime for android:

Exception Description: Entity class [class myPackage.Foo] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.

It is working for java SE project.

My question is: does Dex strip away JPA annotation?  From APK analyzer, I can see the Foo.getId() method, but not sure if the annotation is kept.

### UPDATE

After debugging, the annotation @Id is not lost. It is strange that EclipseLink did not see it.

Comment: maybe you don't have a setId() method and so have not met the constraints of the JPA spec? Maybe the EclipseLink log tells you more? Maybe there is something you're not showing?

Comment: give more code. Exception suggest few sources of problem

Comment: small performance (RAM etc) android devices, and totally different class / obejct life cycle suggest JPA is not too much friendly with android. Few good android friendly libraries exist, f.e. com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow

Comment: If annotations don't work, you can always try orm.xml